# Duplicate users in Umbraco

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am using Umbraco membership provider in MVC application. And today found few emails are duplicated in it. Don't know how. I want to know the root cause behind this issue but I'm not able to reproduce this issue.

What could be the reason behind this issue?

Comment: if you do a fresh installation, does the problem reoccurs?

Comment: I can not do it now, because I am having lot many users in existing DB.

Comment: Where did you notice this? Isn't it possible that the duplicated entries are logically deleted users?